# Printing on roll paper

Tags: c#, .net, printing, crystal-reports, gdi

I am using C# with Winforms. I am trying to print bills on a paper roll. The width of the paper is 3in but the length of the paper is dynamic (its a roll paper). The length depends on how many items are there in the list. E.g. in a purchase if there are 100 items sold then it will be quite long roll while for a single item purchased it would be of small length.

When I print the report, after the end job, printer eject the last page more than I need. It eject paper as long as A4 size. I want to print the required lines, then stop printing. 
I use a roll of paper, not A4 or A3 and an Epson LQ-300 + II printer.

To be more specific, printing is always done to page-sized units. If I set the page to be 3in x 8in then I always end up with a printout that is a multiple of 8in long. If I have a 9in bill to print, I end up with a 16in printout, wasting 7in of paper. How can I print with the last page being only as long as it needs to be?

Here is the code:

```
private void printDoc_PrintPage(Object sender, PrintPageEventArgs e)
        {
            Font printFont = new Font("Courier New", 12);
            int y = 15;
            e.Graphics.DrawString("a Line", printFont, Brushes.Black, 0, y); y = y + 20;
            e.Graphics.DrawString(" Line", printFont, Brushes.Black, 0, y); y = y + 25;
            e.Graphics.DrawString(" Line", printFont, Brushes.Black, 0, y); y = y + 35;
            e.Graphics.DrawString(" Line", printFont, Brushes.Black, 0, y); y = y + 45;
        }
```

Comment: What is your question? You should just be able to continue printing until you're done. Then you'll be finished. That's the advantage of roll paper.

Comment: +1, just keep on drawing until you are done and finish up with a statement to cut the paper. I used to do this using GDI, no experience with Crystal reports

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Have you tried using a page that is only "one line" long?

Omit the upper and lower border, and you can print non stop.

Now add a bit (So the page can be torn off) and eject that.

Try this:

```
            PaperSize pkCustomSize1 = new PaperSize("First custom size", 100, 200);

            printDoc.DefaultPageSettings.PaperSize = pkCustomSize1
```

See: 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.printing.pagesettings.papersize.aspx

Comment: Given the constraints, this seems like the most logical answer.

Comment: How can we define a single line paper?, I have seen only standard sizes in printer setting.

Comment: is there any alternative option in vb.net without specifying height as one line? If it is not then what type of coding they are used in point of sale terminal to print the receipts which also fixed width and varying height for each bill?

Comment: Guys, am also struggling with this. Where is the one line above, I see you have set the height to 200 how is that one line.

Answer (score 5):

You can also adjust the paper size on the fly.  Less work to do it one line per page, but I'd imagine this would produce a nicer print preview if anyone were to have cause to do that:

```
printdoc.DefaultPageSettings.PaperSize.Height += lineheight;
```

Comment: this coding not working for me. in which event i should specify this coding?.. i used in on print page event..

Comment: You'd want to do that as you draw each line. And you'd want to start with a custom one line paper size as the accepted answer suggested. Height isn't writable for standard paper sizes.

Answer (score 1):

I'm using the VKP80II and what I do is i set the pagesettings.papersize to:

```
PaperSize PaperRoll= new PaperSize("Paper Roll", 300, 0);
```

automatically it prints the exact length that it needs to without me actually specifying the length

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you can define a custom paper size and use it in your report.

Open printer folder (from Control Panel).

Open **Server Properties** from the file menu. It will open **Printer and Server Properties** Dialogue box.

Select Check **Create a new Form**

Specify page width height. I suggest you make your height 3 inches.

Now click on the **Save Form** button.

Your custom page is ready.

set this paper as your default paper size both in the report as well as in the printer properties.

Now you are good to go.

Comment: should have at least specified what operating system your using for this.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the print preview option to complete this process.

```
// This is for the print preview event
 private void printPreviewDialog1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
     int j = 0;
     z = 185;

     while (j < dataGridView1.Rows.Count)
     {                 
         j += 1;
         z += 30;
     }

     z += 60;

     PaperSize pkCustomSize1 = new PaperSize("First custom size", 350, z);

     printDocument1.DefaultPageSettings.PaperSize = pkCustomSize1;
 }

 // This is the loop for generating print Document
 private void printDocument1_PrintPage(object sender, System.Drawing.Printing.PrintPageEventArgs e)
 {
     int i = 0; //For Gridview Row Count
     int sno = 1; //For Grid Serial Number

     e.Graphics.DrawString(
         "HEADING", 
         new Font("Calibri", 20, FontStyle.Bold), 
         Brushes.Black, 
         new Point(100, 5));

     e.Graphics.DrawString(
         "Address", 
         new Font("Calibri", 12, FontStyle.Bold), 
         Brushes.Black, 
         new Point(75, 35));

    int y = 185; //For Grid y axis start to print 

    while (i < dataGridView1.Rows.Count)
    {
        e.Graphics.DrawString(
            sno.ToString(), 
            new Font("Calibri", 10, FontStyle.Bold), 
            Brushes.Black, 
            new Point(10, y)); //For Serial Number

        e.Graphics.DrawString(
            dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[1].FormattedValue.ToString(), 
            new Font("Calibri", 10, FontStyle.Bold), 
            Brushes.Black, 
            new Point(240, y));

        //This is for Trim content to next line
        Graphics df1 = e.Graphics;
        SizeF ef1 = df1.MeasureString(
            dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[0].FormattedValue.ToString(),
            new Font(new FontFamily("Calibri"), 12F, FontStyle.Bold),
            200); //160

        df1.DrawString(
            dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[0].FormattedValue.ToString(),
            new Font(new FontFamily("Calibri"), 12F, FontStyle.Bold), 
            Brushes.Black,
            new RectangleF(new PointF(60.0F, y), ef1), //350.0
            StringFormat.GenericTypographic);

        i += 1;
        sno += 1;
        y += 30;
    }

    e.Graphics.DrawString(
        "------------------------------------------------------------------------------------",
        new Font("Calibri", 10, FontStyle.Bold), 
        Brushes.Black, 
        new Point(0, y));

    e.Graphics.DrawString(
        "Total Amount-:" + TotalAmnt_txt.Text, 
        new Font("Calibri", 10, FontStyle.Bold), 
        Brushes.Black, 
        new Point(150, y+=20));

    e.Graphics.DrawString(
        "------------------------------------------------------------------------------------", 
        new Font("Calibri", 10, FontStyle.Bold), 
        Brushes.Black, 
        new Point(0, y+=20));

    e.Graphics.DrawString(
        "***Care For You ****", 
        new Font("Calibri", 10, FontStyle.Bold), 
        Brushes.Black, 
        new Point(150, y += 20));

    i = 0;
    sno = 1;
}
```