# Can't stop printing

Tags: c#, printing, barcode

I use [this device](http://www.argox.com/content.php?sno=0000067&P_ID=19) to print a barcode but printer doesn't stop printing, giving me empty tags until I shut it down. I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4365360/printing-on-roll-paper) but specifying the Paper Size didn't help me.

The code I use:

```
PrintDocument document = new PrintDocument();
document.DefaultPageSettings.PaperSize =
    new PaperSize("Custom", Centimeters(7), Centimeters(5));
document.PrintPage += (s, a) =>
{
    a.Graphics.DrawString("*123456*",
                          BarcodeFont,
                          new SolidBrush(Color.Black),
                          new Point(0, 0));
}
document.Print();
```

Centimeters Method:

```
// Converts the unit "Hundredths of an inch" to centimeter.
int Centimeters(int centimeters)
{
    return (int)((centimeters * 100) / 2.54);
}
```

It prints the barcode to first tag correctly but it doesn't stop. Tags are 7x5 cm. and I set the paper size according to this, I have no idea what else I can do.

**Edit:** Setting HasMorePages to false didn't help and I know it's not because of the device I use: There are some other programs I currently use to print barcodes and they all work.

Comment: Use the debugger.  Set a breakpoint on the PrintPage lambda code *and* the Print() call.  With significant odds that the Print() call breakpoint hits more than once.  Look at the call stack to see how that happened.

Comment: @Hans, nope, it hits only once.

Comment: Are you changing the print stock?  (Most) Thermal printers need to be re calibrated before it will notice the label size has changed. (sManual_English.pdf p27)

Comment: this question has been 8yr... but I desperately need to know the solution for this... hopefully Safak looking at this message...

Comment: Sorry @EHOng, this was on my first job and I came to an age where I can't even remember what I had for breakfast anymore. :) I don't have anything backed up from that era to refer to either. The only thing I remember about that application is that we actually shipped it, and it was printing ok (I know that doesn't help much - sorry again for not updating here on time).

Answer (score 5):

Set the `HasMorePages` property of the `eventArgs` to false:

```
document.PrintPage += (s, a) =>
{
    a.Graphics.DrawString("*123456*",
                          BarcodeFont,
                          new SolidBrush(Color.Black),
                          new Point(0, 0));
    a.HasMorePages = false;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer but it didn't work. It still keeps going until I turn off the power switch.

Comment: It is already false, this is not the cause.